# I want to make a list of names in a textfield and then be able to click on each name

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, textfield

I am attempting to make an admin site for a project that is on Firebase.  Most of the site's pages have a large text fields that is supposed to hold all the current items that can be modified.

For example:
The user management page has text fields on the left to show all the information of a user and on the right is a large text field that I want to be able to load the names of users into and then be able to select one and load the information of that user from the Firebase user database into the left fields.  I would then want to be able to alter and save those values.

My current dilemma is I don't understand how to implement the right side.  I understand the basic process for writing to the text field, however, I don't know how I would be able to make them selectable.  Since this is common enough in Windows windows, I know there is a way to do it, but I don't know how.  I am also a bit foggy on how to separate the names into individual objects.

An example of what I am trying to create is similar to the windows uninstall a program window[or this window showing the list of users in a properties window

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGOjr.png

What commands might help me achieve what I am looking to do?

Comment: Hey Josh, please check out the [Stack Overflow Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [Minimal, Reproducible Example Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @CalvinBonner With all due respect, could you please be more blunt about what you are saying?  Are you saying that I must have already figured out how to do this and I can only ask about bugs or what exactly.  I thought I was concise with what I wanted to achieve.  If it is not concise enough, would images of what I am trying to create be helpful?

Comment: An example of what you are looking for or examples of what you have tried would almost definitely be necessary in order for anyone to post a helpful answer for you. If you check out the [pages I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you should see some great examples of what I am talking about.

Comment: I haven't really started this feature yet because I don't know how.  The most I have is a large text field.  I want to create something like the windows uninstall a program window.

A list of items in a field that I can click to select.

Comment: If that's the case, it's probably a bit early to be looking to Stackoverflow. Try researching on the wider web and come back to Stack if you have a more specific or "[Focused](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" question.

Comment: I tried researching first.  I can't find an article on this.  The stuff I found didn't apply.  That's why I am asking questions here.  If I could solve this via research, then I would.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "list boxes". Try googling that! Stack overflow is really picky about you needing to show some code in your question of what you've tried -- I understand your frustration of not knowing where to look.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my best understanding of your question and the picture you posted, I have created a working prototype. This is just using vanilla JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. I'm sure it will look a little different in implementation, but hopefully it's close enough to give you a jumping-off point.

#### UPDATE:

I updated my answer based on Sensoray's comment.

```js
//create an object of users
let Users = [
  {
    "name": " Fro Doe",
    "id": "user1",
    "snack": "Chips"
  },
  {
    "name": " Mare Ree",
    "id": "user2",
    "snack": "Bananas"
  },
  {
    "name": " Sam Wise",
    "id": "user3",
    "snack": "Candy"
  },
]

//identify our list element
let list = document.querySelector('#user-list');

//loop through users in out Users object and add them to the list
for (var i = 0; i < Users.length; i ++) {
  let newItem = document.createElement('option');
  newItem.innerHTML = Users[i].name;
  newItem.id = Users[i].id;
  if (i == 0) {
    newItem.className = "active";
  }
  list.appendChild(newItem);
}

list.size = Users.length;

updateResponse(list.firstChild);

//collect all the list items
let listItems = list.querySelectorAll('option');

//loop through the list itmes and add a click listener to each that toggles the 'active' state
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i ++) {
  listItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
      for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i ++) {
        listItems[i].classList.remove('active');
      }
      e.target.classList.add('active');
      
      updateResponse(e.target);
    }
  })
}

function updateResponse(element) {
  //collect the response element
  let response = document.querySelector('#response');
  
  //collect each input from the response element
  responseId = response.querySelector('.response-id');
  responseName = response.querySelector('.response-name');
  responseSnack = response.querySelector('.response-snack');
  
  //find the matching user in the users object and update the inputs to match
  for (var i = 0; i < Users.length; i ++) {
    if (Users[i].id == element.id) {
      responseId.value = Users[i].id;
      responseName.value = Users[i].name;
      responseSnack.value = Users[i].snack;
    }
  }
  
}

function updateUser() {
    //collect the response element
  let response = document.querySelector('#response');
  
  //collect each input from the response element
  responseId = response.querySelector('.response-id');
  responseName = response.querySelector('.response-name');
  responseSnack = response.querySelector('.response-snack');
  
  //update the js object values
  for (var i = 0; i < Users.length; i ++) {
    if (Users[i].id == responseId.value) {
      Users[i].name = responseName.value;
      Users[i].snack = responseSnack.value;
    }
  }
  
  //update the list
  //find current list item
  let curItem = list.querySelector('#'+responseId.value);
  //update the text on the item
  curItem.innerText = responseName.value;
  
  //keep the page from redirecting
  return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Variable Text", system-ui, ui-rounded, sans-serif;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 32px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Variable Display", system-ui, ui-rounded, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .parent {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
}

select {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ABABAB;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
option {
  padding: 8px 4px;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="right">
    <h1>Users:</h1>
    <select name="user-list" size="3" id="user-list"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <h1>User Info:</h1>
    <form id="response" onsubmit="return updateUser()">
      <label for="id">User ID:</label><input type="text" name="id" class="response-id" disabled></input>
      <label for="name">User Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" class="response-name"></input>
      <label for="snack">User's Favorite Snack:</label><input type="text" name="snack" class="response-snack"></input>
      <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for all your help.  How much time you spent doing all this to answer my question is insane.  Thank you!